# Key Authentication: no prompt when pushing to remote repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh

I have setup a remote git repo - using private key authentication over SSH.
The private key is password protected.

This works from my commandline git (on Windows):

```
PS C:\Users\me\myrepo> git push -u origin --all
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\me\.ssh\git_rsa': [human enters password here]
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 425 bytes | 70.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
[...]
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

On the same Windows box - I have [configured](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_configuring-key-based-authentication) Visual Studio Code to use the same private key as the commandline.
When I push to the remote repository using Visual Studio Code - I get an error message:

```
[Visual Studio Code]
(X) Git: git@git.acme.com: Permission denied(publickey).
```

[image]

The UI never prompts me for the private-key password: is this the problem?

I have configured the following Visual Studio Code configuration:

```
@ext:ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh,ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit config file
```

To point at my SSH configuration file, which looks like this:

```
Host git.acme.com
    User git
    HostName git.acme.com
    Port 8000
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_rsa
```

And I can confirm that the file exists (and as above -  this works from commandline git - where I point at the same file using `$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND` instead of config file).

```
PS C:\Users\me> gci ~/.ssh/git_rsa|select-object -Property FullName

FullName
--------
C:\Users\me\.ssh\git_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting the password from "Credentials Manager" in the control panel. Windows stores the details there and once used it never shows the prompt.

Comment: I checked - Credential Manager doesn't seem to have anything that corresponds with the user unfortunately.
Thanks though - good idea.